# Can a jar library bound via Xamarin.Bindings library project start a service in Xamarin.Android project?

Tags: android, xamarin, jar

I've bound a native Java code to my Xamarin.Android project, by creating Xamarin.Bindings library. I've noticed that I can't make this library to do anything useful. I went into the decompiled code of the JAR library, and saw, that it tries to start background services like so:

```
context.startService
```

or

```
context.bindService
```

I monitored the application through the Device Monitor, and saw that it is unable to start all kinds of services, which this jar library needs in order to function.
The exact error message is, for instance:

```
02-19 19:04:45.882: W/ActivityManager(1570): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.redacted1.redacted2.REDACTED2 pkg=com.redacted1.redacted2 } U=0: not found
```

The numbers after "redacted" parts show if the two words are the same, regardless of the case.

I am wondering, is there a way to make this work - i.e. to add some transformation or permission, to make it possible for these services start?

I tried to search for this specific issue, but couldn't find anything so far. Any pointers will be welcome.

Comment: Did you step by step to binding Jar?https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/ ,If you did that, you could make a basic troubleshot bindings by yourself.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/

Comment: Yeah, I did. I guess the real problem is that intent is started with the class and package name, which don’t exist in jar itself. It goes something like: this.context.startService(new Intent(). setComponent(new ComponentName(“pkg”, “class”). But neither “pkg” nor class exist in the jar. I’m pretty sure they have to be present, for the service to start.

Comment: Yes, these issue normally related to this jar itself, You could change another jar to test it. If this issue is disappear, you should change code of jar or use another.

Comment: Thank you. The jar was kind of handed to me - so I can’t really change it. But your answer will help me to explain this, to my boss))

Comment: You are welcome.Can I post my comment as answer? And accept it so this questions gets marked as answered. Helps other searching for questions to help on so they don't waste time on questions that are answered.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is the answer, please post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issue related to this jar itself normally , you could change another jar to test it. If this issue is disappear, you should change code of jar or use another.